# ruby syntax highlighting lost on long files

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-ruby

With a "long" ruby file (896 lines in my case) the ruby syntax highlighting is lost when I `G` to the bottom of the file. Once that happens and I go back to the top with `gg`, the syntax highlighting remains off. The only way to get the syntax highlighting back is to just reload the file with `:e`.

However, if I just `<CTRL-F>` from the top all the way to the bottom, then the syntax highlighting remains.

This is a bit similar to [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10114/syntax-highlighting-randomly-turns-off) but definitely not the same, as this happens every time I follow the steps listed above. Highlighting for my :help or .vimrc files is NOT lost, even though my .vimrc file is over 1000 lines long [I know, I know... I have to reorganize this; just haven't had time:].

My syntax-specific plugins include the following; I guess the next thing to try is to remove them one at a time and see which one is the perp.

```
.vim/bundle/Decho/syntax
.vim/bundle/nerdtree/syntax
.vim/bundle/tagbar/syntax
.vim/bundle/tmux.vim/vim/syntax
.vim/bundle/vim-coffee-script/after/syntax
.vim/bundle/vim-coffee-script/syntax
.vim/bundle/vim-cucumber/syntax
.vim/bundle/vim-haml/syntax
.vim/bundle/vim-javascript/syntax
.vim/bundle/vim-jsx/after/syntax
.vim/bundle/vim-markdown/syntax
.vim/bundle/vim-ruby/syntax
.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/syntax
.vim/bundle/vimoutliner/syntax
.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/syntax
.vim/eclim/syntax
.vim/Plugin/mpc/syntax
```

And the last change is:

```
  filetype=ruby
        Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0692/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
```

So not much information there.

This only started happening "recently" (past few weeks, plus my machine was re-imaged for macOS Sierra and I've now got the latest versions of everything).

Happens both inside/outside of tmux

Any suggestions besides the brute force approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a synchronization issue. Try

```
:syntax sync maxlines=1000
```

Find the details in `:help :syn-sync`

Comment: Already tried the following which do not work: `:syntax sync fromstart`, `:syn off | syn on`, `:redraw`, and various combinations of your `:syntax sync maxlines=1000`plus combinations with `minlines=`